# Unable to partition internal disk on El Capitan

Tags: macos, partition

I'm trying to install Linux on my MacBook Air but seem to have fallen at the first hurdle and am unable to partition my disk.  I open Disk Utility, I have ~70GB of free space and when I click partition at the top it starts the process.

What I then find is that Disk Utility says "Incorrect number of file hard links" and "Invalid directory item count".

I have also tried to run first aid on my Macintosh HD, the same messages come up but then Disk Utility just says that the First Aid process is complete, leaving me still unable to partition my disk.

Is there anyway I can fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever create hard links in the terminal? Sounds like you need to delete them properly.

If that doesn't work you may need something like DiskWarrior to repair your drive.

If all that fails, backup your hard drive, re-initialize and re-partition.

Good luck!

Comment: If I'm honest I'm not completely certain what a hard link is, it's like a shortcut right? Is there a way I can view the hard links that I have on my Mac?

Comment: Yes they are similar to shortcuts but different. Well if you didn't create some of your own it may be indicating the file system hard links are not right. You should make sure you have everything on that drive backed up. Research UNIX hard links online for more info. Otherwise, you need something better than "First Aid" to repair your disk, or wipe it and start from scratch.

Comment: Fantastic.  I have back ups, and starting again sounds like it could be a good idea.  Thanks for your help!